# PHP: Insert quotes at the beginning and end of a string

Tags: php, string, quotes

I have this string:

> $str = 'Small ship in the sea';

I'd like to have this output:

> "Small ship in the sea"

How can I accomplish this in PHP?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: The answers provided are pretty obvious. I wanted to provide a simple example, what I'm actually doing is loading a huge text file and each line is stored in multiple arrays. So each array should have the quotes at the end and at the beginning, so what would be a solution to the example provided before? Maybe using regex to add the quotes?

EDIT 2:

Apologies for the confusion this is my code:

> $users = file('xls/try_traffic.txt'); //Load File
>
> $users = preg_replace('/, TG=\d{3}/', '', $users);
>
> $users = str_replace("LABEL=", "", $users);
>
> $users = str_replace('"', "", $users);
>
> $users = preg_replace("/\t/", '","', $users);
>
> print_r($users);

I get this output (the simple version):

> Array ( [0] => 01/16/2014 00:00:00","30","TLAGMSC1-MSX","TMXCABINLC
>
> [1] => 01/16/2014 00:00:00","30","TLAGMSC1-MSX","TMXLPZOGMV
>
> [2] => 01/16/2014 00:00:00","30","TLAGMSC1-MSX","TMXLPZ2WLD1
>
> )

So I want to add the quotes at the beginning and end of each, so it looks like this:

> Array ( [0] => "01/16/2014 00:00:00","30","TLAGMSC1-MSX","TMXCABINLC"
>
> [1] => "01/16/2014 00:00:00","30","TLAGMSC1-MSX","TMXLPZOGMV"
>
> [2] => "01/16/2014 00:00:00","30","TLAGMSC1-MSX","TMXLPZ2WLD1"
>
> )

Comment: String concatenation: use the dot `.`.

Comment: I'm confused.  Why are you storing each line in multiple arrays?  Shouldn't each line be an element in a single array?  Can you show an example of the contents of the text file and the end result you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want: ***EDIT 5***

```
foreach ($users as $k => $v) {
    $users[$k] = (substr($v, 0, 1) == '"') ? ($v) : ('"'. $v);
    $users[$k] = (substr($v, strlen($v) -1) == '"') ? ($v) : ($v .'"');
}
print_r($users);
```

Check out [PHP String Documentation](http://php.net/string) for more details on how to deal with strings in PHP.

Personally, I use single quotes all the time, and only when absolutely necessary do I use doublequotes. It's much easier to predict string behavior with that approach IMO. Hope this helps!

Comment: Please look at the EDIT section in the description.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "each line is stored in arrays"? When you read a file, you read it file_get_contents(), and it's not in the form of an array. Can you explain what you mean? I'd like to help.

Comment: Thanks for your code and Apologies for the confusion, I edited the answer again.

Comment: No problem! I've edited my answer above. I think it's what you're looking for.

Comment: No problem! I edited it _one_ more time for your review. It might operate better than EDIT 3

Comment: It works better thanks! Just notice that you added an extra ')' in the  second line (substr($v, 0, 1)) == '"') other than that it's perfect, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Why not just make use of the concatenation **`.`** operator ?

```
<?php
$str = 'Small ship in the sea';
echo '"'.$str.'"'; //"prints" "Small ship in the sea"
```

---

> The answers provided are pretty obvious. I wanted to put a simple
>   example, what I'm actually doing is loading a huge text file and each
>   line is stored in multiple arrays. So each array should have the
>   quotes at the end and at the beginning.

### The code

```
<?php
$arr = file('yourtextfile.txt');
$new_arr = array_map('addquote',$arr);

function addquote($v)
{
return '"'.$v.'"';
}

print_r($new_arr);
```

Comment: The concatenation operator would work, but it wouldn't store the double-quotes within the variable. They would only be displayed if implicitly written within the print statement.

Comment: Please look at the EDIT section in the description.

Comment: @user3288852, Check the edited answer for your edited question.

Comment: Thanks, I tested this and didn't worked for my case. Apologies for the confusion, I edited the answer again.